# i18next localization and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, i18next

I am working with [i18next](http://i18next.com/) localization for javascript. Since I am combining PHP and javascript and i need to have localization for 3 languages (en,de,fr) I am facing a small problem. Today I started to work the first time with i18next library and everything is working fine when translating normal tags like div,ul,... The problem I am facing are the pictures. Since I need to have for every language different picture I am not sure is this possible with i18next library, to set a value in tag parameters. For example:

```
document.write('<form action="dropzone.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" style="background-image: url(languages/fr/design.png);" method="post"><div class="fallback" data-i18n="design"><input name="file" type="file" multiple /></div></form>');
```

And the thing I need to change here is the style, this part:

```
style="background-image: url(languages/fr/design.png);"
```

this is not always the same, design.png image is different depending on language setting from url, for example:

```
localhost/designer/box/test.php?lang=fr
```

Is there a way to change this with i18next library, to be for every lang different image path, like this:

```
url(languages/en/design.png)
url(languages/de/design.png)
url(languages/fr/design.png)
```

inside the document.write? Or is there a way to get the value from lang parameter in url in javascript (without the RegEx, this would be like my last solution to make it with the RegEx)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [i18next doc](http://i18next.com/docs/api/#language), you can use `i18next.language` to get the current language i18next is using.

```
var lang = i18next.language
var style="background-image: url(languages/"+ lang +"/design.png);"
console.log(style);
```

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jeu6Lo0/2/)